# Ubuntu 19.04 requires frequent reset of network-manager

Tags: drivers, network-manager, 19.04

I have a System 76 serval. The wifi stops working frequently and the network-manager service needs to be restarted. It will die on its own, but can be triggered by switching wifi 3 times (sometimes more, sometimes fewer)!

When it is working, I have:

```
    % usr/bin/sudo nmcli device
    DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION 
    wlp62s0          wifi      connected     ATT964     
    p2p-dev-wlp62s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected  --         
    enp59s0          ethernet  unavailable   --         
    lo               loopback  unmanaged     --   
    % /usr/bin/sudo lshw -C network
     ...snip...
      *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Wireless 8260
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:3e:00.0
           logical name: wlp62s0
           version: 3a
           serial: e4:b3:18:e3:11:e7
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-21-generic firmware=36.9f0a2d68.0 ip=192.168.1.64 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
           resources: irq:133 memory:dc200000-dc201fff
    % /usr/bin/sudo lspci -vnnn | grep -A 9 Network
    3e:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 [8086:1010]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
        Memory at dc200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number e4-b3-18-ff-ff-e3-11-e7
        Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
```

If I switch between my two wifi routers three times (sometimes more times) using the Select Network command on the taskbar, wifi stops working.

Issuing the commands above yields the following differences:

```
    % /usr/bin/sudo nmcli device
    DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
    enp59s0          ethernet  unavailable  --         
    wlp62s0          wifi      unavailable  --         
    p2p-dev-wlp62s0  wifi-p2p  unavailable  --         
    lo               loopback  unmanaged

    % /usr/bin/sudo lshw -C network
     ...snip...
      *-network
     ...snip...
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-21-generic firmware=36.9f0a2d68.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

/var/log/syslog reports the following after failing to switch wifi networks:

```
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5482] device (wlp62s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5482] device (wlp62s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5485] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5548] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="1574892b-31aa-43ae-a67a-bd732876e327" name="ATT964" pid=21476 uid=1010 result="success"
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5550] device (wlp62s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5562] dhcp4 (wlp62s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2181
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5562] dhcp4 (wlp62s0): state changed bound -> done
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5572] dhcp6 (wlp62s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2318
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5572] dhcp6 (wlp62s0): state changed bound -> done
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval kernel: [209888.953314] wlp62s0: deauthenticating from 10:7b:ef:cc:ab:a3 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp62s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=10:7b:ef:cc:ab:a3 reason=3 locally_generated=1
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp62s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=0 noise=9999 txrate=0
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5688] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5692] device (wlp62s0): Activation: starting connection 'ATT964' (1574892b-31aa-43ae-a67a-bd732876e327)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <warn>  [1563330032.5700] sup-iface[0x55d1a0552930,wlp62s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5701] device (wlp62s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5702] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5713] device (wlp62s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5718] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5724] device (wlp62s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5731] device (wlp62s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'ATT964' has security, but secrets are required.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5731] device (wlp62s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5734] sup-iface[0x55d1a0552930,wlp62s0]: wps: type pbc start...
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5751] device (wlp62s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5756] device (wlp62s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5762] device (wlp62s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'ATT964' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5763] Config: added 'ssid' value 'ATT964'
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5763] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5763] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5763] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330032.5763] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval thunderbird.desktop[21684]: JavaScript error: jar:file:///usr/lib/thunderbird/omni.ja!/components/imCore.js, line 127: TypeError: this._idleService is undefined
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x55794265e560), has been already deallocated — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: == Stack trace for context 0x557942afd240 ==
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #0   55797e02f1d8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1318 (7fdd53a73b80 @ 56)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #1   55797e02f140 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335 (7fdd53a73c10 @ 113)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #2   55797e02f0a0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029 (7fdd53a75e50 @ 216)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #3   55797e02f020 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1924 (7fdd53a75a60 @ 80)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #4   7fff937a95e0 b   self-hosted:979 (7fdd53c50940 @ 440)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: JS ERROR: TypeError: connection.get_setting_ip4_config is not a function#012_isHotSpotMaster@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1322:25#012getIndicatorIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335:13#012_updateIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029:52#012_syncNMState@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1924:9
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x55794265e560), has been already deallocated — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: == Stack trace for context 0x557942afd240 ==
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #0   55797e02f1e8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1318 (7fdd53a73b80 @ 56)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #1   55797e02f150 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335 (7fdd53a73c10 @ 113)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #2   55797e02f0b0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029 (7fdd53a75e50 @ 216)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #3   55797e02f020 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1832 (7fdd53a75430 @ 138)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #4   7fff937a95e0 b   self-hosted:979 (7fdd53c50940 @ 440)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: == Stack trace for context 0x557942afd240 ==
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #0   55797e02f0c8 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/GObject.js:468 (7fdd7c2b90d0 @ 25)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #1   55797e02f020 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1805 (7fdd53a753a0 @ 111)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #2   7fff937a95e0 b   self-hosted:979 (7fdd53c50940 @ 440)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: JS ERROR: TypeError: connection.get_setting_ip4_config is not a function#012_isHotSpotMaster@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1322:25#012getIndicatorIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335:13#012_updateIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029:52#012_syncVpnConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1832:9
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x55794265e560), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gsd-sharing[3554]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gsd-sharing[3554]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval dbus-daemon[1296]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8704' (uid=0 pid=617 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval systemd[1]: resolvconf-pull-resolved.service: Succeeded.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gsd-sharing[21582]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gsd-sharing[21582]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval dbus-daemon[1296]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp62s0]: new request (2 scripts)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp62s0]: start running ordered scripts...
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x55794265e560), has been already deallocated — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: == Stack trace for context 0x557942afd240 ==
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #0   55797e02f1d8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1318 (7fdd53a73b80 @ 56)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #1   55797e02f140 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335 (7fdd53a73c10 @ 113)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #2   55797e02f0a0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029 (7fdd53a75e50 @ 216)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #3   55797e02f020 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1924 (7fdd53a75a60 @ 80)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #4   7fff937a8be0 b   self-hosted:979 (7fdd53c50940 @ 440)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: == Stack trace for context 0x557942afd240 ==
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #0   55797e02f0c8 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/GObject.js:468 (7fdd7c2b90d0 @ 25)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #1   55797e02f020 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1805 (7fdd53a753a0 @ 111)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #2   7fff937a8be0 b   self-hosted:979 (7fdd53c50940 @ 440)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: JS ERROR: TypeError: connection.get_setting_ip4_config is not a function#012_isHotSpotMaster@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1322:25#012getIndicatorIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335:13#012_updateIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029:52#012_syncNMState@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1924:9
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x55794265e560), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp62s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp62s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x55794265e560), has been already deallocated — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: == Stack trace for context 0x557942afd240 ==
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #0   55797e02f1e8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1318 (7fdd53a73b80 @ 56)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #1   55797e02f150 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335 (7fdd53a73c10 @ 113)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #2   55797e02f0b0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029 (7fdd53a75e50 @ 216)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #3   55797e02f020 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1832 (7fdd53a75430 @ 138)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #4   7fff937a8be0 b   self-hosted:979 (7fdd53c50940 @ 440)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: JS ERROR: TypeError: connection.get_setting_ip4_config is not a function#012_isHotSpotMaster@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1322:25#012getIndicatorIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335:13#012_updateIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029:52#012_syncVpnConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1832:9
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x55794265e560), has been already deallocated — impossible to get any property from it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: == Stack trace for context 0x557942afd240 ==
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #0   7fff937a6d30 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1318 (7fdd53a73b80 @ 56)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #1   55797e02f140 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335 (7fdd53a73c10 @ 113)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #2   55797e02f0a0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029 (7fdd53a75e50 @ 216)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #3   55797e02f020 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1924 (7fdd53a75a60 @ 80)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #4   7fff937a8be0 b   self-hosted:979 (7fdd53c50940 @ 440)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: == Stack trace for context 0x557942afd240 ==
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #0   55797e02f0c8 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/GObject.js:468 (7fdd7c2b90d0 @ 25)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #1   55797e02f020 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1805 (7fdd53a753a0 @ 111)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval org.gnome.Shell.desktop[21476]: #2   7fff937a8be0 b   self-hosted:979 (7fdd53c50940 @ 440)
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: JS ERROR: TypeError: connection.get_setting_ip4_config is not a function#012_isHotSpotMaster@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1322:25#012getIndicatorIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1335:13#012_updateIcon@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:2029:52#012_syncNMState@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1924:9
    Jul 16 19:20:32 serval gnome-shell[21476]: Object NM.ActiveConnection (0x55794265e560), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
    Jul 16 19:20:33 serval chromium-browser.desktop[21476]: [20638:20661:0716/192033.063146:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(413)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
    Jul 16 19:20:33 serval goa-daemon[3447]: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.27 was not provided by any .service files
    Jul 16 19:20:33 serval goa-daemon[3447]: secret_password_lookup_sync() failed: The name :1.27 was not provided by any .service files
    Jul 16 19:20:33 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330033.6350] device (wlp62s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
    Jul 16 19:20:33 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330033.6351] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp62s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 60:fe:20:57:c4:4e (SSID='ATT964' freq=2457 MHz)
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval kernel: [209890.593553] wlp62s0: authenticate with 60:fe:20:57:c4:4e
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330034.2076] device (wlp62s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330034.2077] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval kernel: [209890.600168] wlp62s0: send auth to 60:fe:20:57:c4:4e (try 1/3)
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp62s0: Trying to associate with 60:fe:20:57:c4:4e (SSID='ATT964' freq=2457 MHz)
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval kernel: [209890.623554] wlp62s0: authenticated
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330034.2357] device (wlp62s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330034.2357] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval kernel: [209890.631825] wlp62s0: associate with 60:fe:20:57:c4:4e (try 1/3)
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval kernel: [209890.635686] wlp62s0: RX AssocResp from 60:fe:20:57:c4:4e (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp62s0: Associated with 60:fe:20:57:c4:4e
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval wpa_supplicant[667]: wlp62s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval kernel: [209890.638188] wlp62s0: associated
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330034.2504] device (wlp62s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
    Jul 16 19:20:34 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330034.2504] device (p2p-dev-wlp62s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
```

...snip...

```
    Jul 16 19:20:45 serval NetworkManager[617]: <info>  [1563330045.2179] supplicant: wpa_supplicant die count reset
    Jul 16 19:20:45 serval NetworkManager[617]: <warn>  [1563330045.2180] device (wlp62s0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#1).
    Jul 16 19:20:46 serval systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
```

Comment: After 17 days of no comments, I'm turning this into a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1838836

Answer (score 0):

Connecting through cable to same router and running `sudo service network-manager restart` solved my similar issue.